# YiiFramework ServerPilot CDbConnection could not find extension

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii

I have just setup a Yii Framework web app on serverpilot.io but cannot connect to database. If I try to connect directly using mysql_connect or PDO, it does not error.

```
$mysqlConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx", "yyy", "zzz");
```

These are my PDO Drivers: dblib, mysql, odbc, pgsql, sqlite. And this is my pdo_mysql version: mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: f59eb767fe17a6679589b5c076d9fa88d3d4eac0 $

From what I see in phpinfo, the pdo_mysql is already installed, is there anything I miss ? Thank you.

[EDITED]

This is my config:

```
array(
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx',
    'emulatePrepare' => false,
    'username' => 'yyy', 
    'password' => 'zzz',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'class'=>'application.extensions.PHPPDO.CPdoDbConnection',
    'pdoClass' => 'PHPPDO',
    'enableProfiling' => true,
    'enableParamLogging' => true
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the cause. I just knew that mysql_connect is deprecated in PHP 7. By default the PHP version in serverpilot is PHP 7 and I'm using PHPPDO extension which uses mysql extension not mysqli. That's why if I try to connect manually it does not throw error but throws error everytime I try to connect using Yii. Hope this helps someone who might face the same issue.